# Can I use one Job instead of two Jobs when I use Flow in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

In Code A, there are two Flows, and I assign two jobs for them, I collect the two Flows in `fun beginSoundDensity()` and stop collecting the two Flows in `fun resetSoundDensity()`.

I think there are many repeated codes in Code A, so I hope to improve it, but Code B doesn't work.

Can  I use one Job in my case?

**Code A**

```
private val _soundDensityState = MutableStateFlow(initialMSoundDensity)
val soundDensityState = _soundDensityState.asStateFlow()

private val _timeX = MutableStateFlow(0)
val timeX = _timeX.asStateFlow()

private var myJob1: Job?=null
private var myJob2: Job?=null

val myFlow: Flow<Int> = flow {
    var i = 0
    while (true) {
        emit(i)
        i = i + 15
        delay(5000)
    }
}

fun beginSoundDensity() {
        myJob1?.cancel()
        myJob2?.cancel()

        myJob1 = viewModelScope.launch {
            aSoundMeter.startSoundDensity {
                pauseSoundDensity()  
            }.cancellable()
                .collect {
                    _soundDensityState.value = it
                }
        }

        myJob2 = viewModelScope.launch {
            myFlow.collect {
                _timeX.value = it
            }
        }

    }
}

fun resetSoundDensity(){
    myJob1?.cancel()
    myJob2?.cancel()
}
```

**Code B**

```
//The same

private var myJob: Job?=null       

val myFlow: Flow<Int> = flow {
    var i = 0
    while (true) {
        emit(i)
        i = i + 15
        delay(5000)
    }
}

fun beginSoundDensity() {
        myJob?.cancel()
        
        myJob = viewModelScope.launch {
            aSoundMeter.startSoundDensity {
                pauseSoundDensity()  
            }.cancellable()
                .collect {
                    _soundDensityState.value = it
                }

            myFlow.collect {
                _timeX.value = it      //It will not be launched
            }
        }
      
    }
}

fun resetSoundDensity(){
    myJob?.cancel()       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. You need two separate coroutines running concurrently to collect from two flows. In your Code B `myFlow` will be collected only after `aSoundMeter` finishes collecting. Collections need to run at the same time, so you need two concurrent coroutines for this purpose.

However, if you always start and cancel both collections together, then I think it would be better to group them into a single coroutine like this:

```kotlin
fun beginSoundDensity() {
    myJob?.cancel()
        
    myJob = viewModelScope.launch {
        coroutineScope {
            launch {
                aSoundMeter.startSoundDensity {
                    pauseSoundDensity()  
                }.cancellable()
                    .collect {
                        _soundDensityState.value = it
                    }
            }
            launch {
                myFlow.collect {
                    _timeX.value = it      //It will not be launched
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun resetSoundDensity(){
    myJob?.cancel()       
}
```